# Check console errors generated by browser upon loading list of URLs

Tags: javascript, web-browser

I have around 650 URLs in a excel document. Now my job is to access the URLs and check if the console is showing any errors or warnings. It is tedious job t access each URL once in a browser and check the console errors.
Do we have any online tools or other softwares that will minimize my work.

Comment: What do you mean by "check"? Is writing all of the errors to a text file enough?

Comment: Any browser is OK? For instance command-line-based browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think the W3C link checker might be a good tool.

Have a look at the github directory: https://github.com/w3c/link-checker.git
or at https://www.w3.org/2007/OWL/draft/tr-checks/checklinks-13-owl2-dr-linear.html